# On Success in Jquery load the div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the jQuery code as :

```js
function delete_buyer(val) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax_delete_supplier.php",
    data: 'id=' + val,
    success: function(data) {
      $("#msg").html(data);
      $("#pks1").load("buyer_details.php");
    }
  });
}
```

> jquery.min.js:4 [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

Where if the result is success then the table will be reloaded/refreshed. But the div is not getting refreshed.

Can you help me out where i went wrong, Thank You!

Comment: The logic would dictate that `success` is not being hit. Check the console to see exactly what is happening when the AJAX request runs

Comment: You need to check the server's response first. What would be helpful would be if you checked and posted posted the response you get in your `Network` tab, under `XHR` in Chrome for example. Looks like you're probably getting a server error

Comment: When ever you use `$.ajax` you should not only add a `success` callback but  always also add an `error` callback, and handle the case when you get an error.

Comment: @t.niese I have added in the main source code . I did'nt added here as that part is not include in my question

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan  Success has been hit because i am getting an html data . I have edit my question with an console message

Comment: What you've shown is a warning, not an error. It means you've used `async: false` somewhere. While that's an issue, it won't cause any immediate problems with your code. It also seems unrelated to the code you've shown so far in the question

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Its showing an error as the div part is going blank with a white screen, and that table visibility is hidden after hitting button

Comment: Are you sure the AJAX request from the `load()` call is working?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan .  Can you help me out how i can check that load() call is working or not??